# java code in inputText

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jstl

i am trying to include a java code into the value of the inputText in my jsf page but an error occur

> according to tld or attribute directive in tag file attribute value
>   does not accept any expressions

Here is my jsf page.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="core" %>
<%@ page language="java" %>
    <core:view>
    <html:form>
        <html:outputLabel value="Informations " style="FONT-SIZE: xx-large;"/>
        <br />&nbsp;
        <br />

        <%
final String property=System.getProperty("jboss.server.home.dir");
 %>
    <html:outputLabel value="Répertoire de configuration:  " />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<html:inputText value='<%=property%>'/>

    </html:form>
    </core:view>
```

Doesn ' t work either with double quote or nothing
How to resolve this problem please ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try Java EL expressions like `value="#{yourBean.property}"`? - You might have to create a bean to get that system property though.

Comment: which version of JSF is that?

Comment: Thank you you two  , The problem is solved!

Comment: @Bozho: perhaps 1.2 as he's still fiddling with legacy JSP files. But I don't think that version will matter much here. Old fashioned *Scriplets* are simply not allowed in JSF tag attribtues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
<html:inputText value='<%=property%>'/>
```

JSF uses Expression Language to populate/read values to/from a JavaBean. You will have to create a POJO action (called ManagedBean) with a variable `property` and link it there.

E.g.

```
public class ConfigurationAction {

    private String property = System.getProperty("jboss.server.home.dir");

    /**NOTE: MUST create a getter and setter. **/
    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to map the ManagedBean. In JBoss Seam, you will just add an `@Name` annotation above the class like, `@Name("configurationAction")`.

Finally, render this in JSF with Expression Language (EL)

```
<html:inputText value="#{configurationAction.property}"/>
```

Where `configurationAction` is the name of your ManagedBean, and `property` is the instance of the ManagedBean.